# Generating access token from refresh token using oauth2 in django

Tags: python, json, django, oauth

I am trying to generate acces token from refresh token in django.
I am using Oauth2.
I am using oauth2 internal url for generating access token
i.e, 127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
I am testing this in Rest Console.

My request is:

```
{ "client_id": "m5JjAzkqOCdH9MC4KV9EAjKuNhdMv2TyNDXgD6T7", "client_secret": "6C495R1BiA0lfXgm7lh0Zvqc6ugB7H6srlwSCLwyVNgoKqK7xGVQbB63Hj97E7fw3tWIgG7tnv9K5nwInaKPaaqSy4FLm8jaBdTPZ8YzlCJMkuiWNbIwc0ltFB7H9cgq",
 "username": "lalit198910",
 "grant_type": "refresh_token",
"token type" : "Bearer",
"refresh_token": "1svsHogo5tq6UxkiY55iMvMpWnGRsn" }
```

the error i am getting is:

```
"error": "unsupported_grant_type"
```

my content type is :

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In Custom headers i have :

```
authorization type:  bearer


value :3nKkSW9TEPjusuy2PzKhFxoTkFlqQC(Access token)
```

Comment: Try `"grant_type": "authorization_code"`

Comment: I tried this one also , but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, 
I was using RAW BODY to pass my request data instead of using Request Paramters